# ML Annotator on WKS showing error

Tags: ibm-watson

I have been trying to launch a ML annotator on WKS however each time I run it fails. All documents are complete and submitted. I am attaching a screenshot of the error too. Any help would be great[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0rcK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have not accepted the annotation.
Navigate to Human Annotation --> select annotation set --> Accept
Now run the ML model.